# Active Directory 2003 32-Bit to 2012

Tags: active-directory

We're moving from a Windows 2003 32-Bit AD setup to a 2012 R2 environment.  My question is whether or not I need to do the upgrade in a step-wise fashion: first to 2008 and then to 2012.  I've read articles that say this is necessary because there is no adprep32.exe on the 2012 install.

[Articles such as this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/05/05/step-by-step-adding-a-windows-server-2012-domain-controller-to-an-existing-windows-2003-network.aspx/) don't mention whether or not the 2003 system was 32 or 64 bit.

Can anyone tell me whether or not the 2008 server will be required?

Thanks.

Edit:  Sorry, I didn't include the fact that it's not an in-place upgrade.  We have a new 2012 server that will be running alongside the 2003.

Comment: Are you standing up a new server for 2012?

Comment: `1.` There's no operating system upgrade path from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2. `2.` You can't upgrade a 32bit edition of Windows to a 64 bit edition of Windows. `3.` You don't need an interim Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2 server, you can deploy a new Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2 Domain Controller in a Windows Server 2003 domain if both the Domain and Forest functional levels are Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADprep does not need to run locally on the actual domain controller. For example, you could bring up your new 2012R2 server, join it do the domain and then perform adprep using that server.

That said, adprep is integrated into the domain controller installation experience, so you should be good to go. Add your 2012R2 server as an additional domain controller to the domain and adprep should run automatically so to speak.

This page documents the new functionality in adprep and specifically mentions the 64/32 bit question: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464018(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot upgrade a 32 bit windows to 64  (even the same version) The simplest solution is to add a new 2012 r2 server to your existing environment migrate any other services over, move the FSMO roles then demote the old server.  If you're keeping the old server you still need something (at least temporarily) to add as a dc (this can be another 2k3 32 bit edition) that can hold a copy of AD while you rebuild the existing server.